# Summarize the data to count occurence of combinations

Tags: python, pandas

I have data for puchases like below

```
User        Product
u1          p1
u1          p2
u2          p1
u3          p5
...         ...
...         ...
...         ...
```

where users is large (order of 10k) and p's are small.

I want to compute a matrix type structure indicating how many people purchased p1, p1 and p2, p1 and p3 etc like below

```
   p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 Total
p1 1  1           2
p2 1              1
p3
p4
p5             1  1
```

I really could not find a way to achieve this..What I have attempted is this..

`pd.pivot_table(df,index='Product',columns='Product').fillna('')`

```
        Num
Product p1  p2  p5
Product         
p1      1.0 
p2          1.0 
p5              1.0
```

what is the standard way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please include your most productive code attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a more clever way to do this, but here is a straightforward approach:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['u1', 'p1'],
                   ['u1', 'p2'],
                   ['u2', 'p1'],
                   ['u3', 'p5']],
                  columns=['User', 'Product'])

products = sorted(list(set(df.Product)))
n_products = len(products)
product_pairs = np.zeros(shape=(n_products, n_products),
                         dtype=int)

for cart in df.groupby('User')['Product'].apply(set):
    for row, p1 in enumerate(products):
        if p1 in cart:
            for col, p2 in enumerate(products):
                if p2 in cart:
                    product_pairs[row, col] += 1

pd.DataFrame(product_pairs, index=products, 
             columns=products)
```

```
    p1  p2  p5
p1  2   1   0
p2  1   1   0
p5  0   0   1
```

Comment: Thank you ! Works great ! I will come back if I have a question. Which is the more clever way..just curious. You mentioned --> "There is probably a more clever way to do this, but....."

Comment: I just wrote that as a cautionary note, because you asked for the standard way to do this, and I would not want to claim that this is it.